# How to label products to indicate cart rule has been applied?

Tags: cart, catalog, rules, shopping

I want to display a product label if a cart rule has been applied to a product but the label is being displayed for all products even those who don't qualify for the cart rules.

Here is the code I am testing:

```
$rules =  Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();?>
        //echo count($rules);

    <?php foreach ($rules as $rule) :?> 
        <?php   $hasPromo=$rule->getConditions()->validate($_product) ;
            if ($hasPromo) 
            {
                $Tag = $rule->getDescription(); 
                ?>
                <div class="libelle-promo"><?php echo $Tag; ?></div>
                <?php 
            }
            else { ?>
            <div class="libelle-promo" style="display: none;"></div>
            <?php } 
          ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $currentcustomerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $proid = $_product->getId(); // your prduct ID

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

        $ruleid = $connection->fetchOne("SELECT `rule_id` FROM `catalogrule_product` WHERE `product_id` ='$proid' 
            AND `customer_group_id` = '$currentcustomerGroupId'");

        $rulename = $connection->fetchOne("SELECT `name` FROM `catalogrule` WHERE `rule_id` = '$ruleid' AND 'is_active' = 1 ");


        echo $rulename;

    ?>
```

Comment: use this code wherever like view page, list, checkout, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply .But i want to display the cart shopping rule not the catalog rule this is why I used applied_rule_ids in sales_quote_item but the label is displayed only if on product is added to to cart . `$tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_quote_item');

```
//echo 'table  : '.$tableName .'<br>';
            $productID=$_product->getId();
            //echo 'productID : '. $productID .'<br>' ;
            $query = 'SELECT applied_rule_ids FROM ' . $tableName . ' WHERE store_id = '
            .$storeId . ' AND ' . 'product_id = '. $productID . ' AND ' . 'applied_rule_ids is NOT NULL' ;
            $rows  = $readConnection->fetchAll($query); 
            $rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                foreach ($row as $singleRow) {
                    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                        if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
                            if ($rule->getRuleId()==$singleRow) { 
                                $Tag = $rule->getDescription(); ?>
                                <div class="libelle-promo"><?php echo $Tag; ?></div>
                                <?php } 
                                else { ?>
                                <div class="libelle-promo" style="display: none;"></div>
                                <?php }
                            } 
                        }
                    } 
                }`
```